# IQueryable .Except() is not resulting what I expect!

Tags: linq

I have the following object:

```
Line{ String Content; Type type;}
```

And I have, `IQeryable<Line>` lines, which I perform operations against. I selected certain lines where `line.Content.Contains('x') = list1`, and now am trying to get to the rest of the lines i.e. lines - list1 and for this am using

```
list2 = lines.Except(list1);
```

but that results in `list2 = lines`.

Code:

```
private
     IQueryable<Line>
     ExtractLines(
     IQueryable<Line> allLines, 
     String keyword, 
     ref IQueryable<Line> hits)
    {

        hits = allLines.Where(lx => lx.Content.Contains(keyword));  

        return allLines.Except(hits); 
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the whole code? This is very messy, it is most likely you've missed something. That is only possible if `list1` is empty.

Comment: None of the lines contain 'x'?

Comment: not really. list1 has +500 items :)

Comment: Just the relevant code. `list1 = lines. ??? ; list2 = lines.Except(list1);`

Comment: Please post your code in its entirety. Debugging it like this is very tricky.

Comment: I might be grasping for straws here, but to what is k bound?

Comment: well, "k" was supposed to be "keyword" and i just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lines` is `IQeryable<Line>`. If you do not save its result, it will run every time you select from it. If `Line` does not override `Equals` and `==`, that will create different objects each time, so `Except` cannot remove the previous object from new objects.

Now, a lot is missing, but try:

```
var linesList = lines.ToList(); // get results ones
var hasX = lines.Where(line => line.Content.Contains('x'));
var noX = lines.Except(hasX);
```

Comment: i will mark this as the answer since it has little bit of an explanation that everyone else could use.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted it yesterday, somehow your edit made it look wrong. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Alright. All I needed to do is to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` in `Line`  class.