# Set Difference of IEnumerable from IQueryable in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists, one is IQueryable and the other is IEnumerable.

I need to find the set difference between them in Linq to Entities like,

IQueryable - IEnumerable, where T is a complex type (class).

When I tried using IQueryable.Except(IEnumerable), it did not work as expected.

```
var listQuery = select query; (listQuery becomes an IQueryable type)
var listEnumerable = (select query).ToList(); (listEnumerable becomes an IEnumerable type)
listQuery.Except(listEnumerable);
```

(This does not perform the expected operation like, imagine, listQuery.Count() is 110 and listEnumerable.Count() is 30, so the final Except() should return 80, instead it returns the whole 110).

Any help?

Thanks
Manikandan J

Comment: An IQueryable is an IEnumerable so your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: If you can, post some example of desired vs actual output, so that others can get the idea what exactly do you want.

Comment: "it did not work as expected". Could you please describe the unexpected behavior that occurred?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/732425/IEnumerable-Vs-IQueryable

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082592/iqueryable-except-is-not-resulting-what-i-expect (might be a dupe, but I'm hesitant to use the dupe hammer here).

Answer (score 1):

IQuerable converts the linq to sql statement and fires it as server whereas IEnumerable has result set in memory and it does all operation in memory rather than server side.

Answer (score 0):

If "Except" is not working (due to custom class type) then you need to implement IEqualityComparer on your custom class.  There's a really good example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: LINQ to Entities doesn't care about equality comparer.