# how to convert from sql query to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I am new to linq, how to convert the following sql query to linq

```
SELECT WorkingHoursID  
  FROM WorkingHours  
except
     ( 
       SELECT WorkingHoursID
         FROM Schedule
        WHERE Date = '2016-08-25'
     GROUP BY WorkingHoursID               
       HAVING COUNT( WorkingHoursID ) >= 8
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Except` method, you can do something like this:

```
var schedules = (from s in DBCon.Schedule
                 where s.Date == new DateTime(2016, 8, 25)
                 group s by s.WorkingHoursID into g
                 where g.Count() >= 8
                 select g.Key).ToList();

var result = DBCon.WorkingHours.Select(item => item.WorkingHoursID).Except(schedules);
```

Comment: Does you code work by passing a list to Queryable.Except?

Comment: yes, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I just changed the following  var result = (from s in DBCon.WorkingHours select s.WorkingHoursID).Except(datalist).ToList();

Comment: @qxg - yes :) [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082592/iqueryable-except-is-not-resulting-what-i-expect) it does seem that it wouldn't have worked if I wouldn't have added to `ToList()` for the `schedules`

Comment: @jody - Glad to here :)

Comment: @GiladGreen, that's different. Your code can't compile. You can write .Query().ToList.Except(...) or .Query().Except().ToList(); You can't write Query.Except(.ToList());

Comment: @qxg - couldn't test it to the DB but with a list of dynamic objects (where the `Schedule` "table" is an `IQueriable` it worked fine.. So.. you can downvote it like you did (apologize if it wasn't you) .. but a) it works, b) The answer was accepted and was said to be working by jody.....

Comment: Gilad, will all my respect, putting `ToList` just to make non working query "working" sounds like quick-and-dirty fix. When used with real queryables, it totally changes the execution plan from single db query to memory, which can have quite negative impact on performance/memory consumption. (btw, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @IvanStoev - I accept what you say and I'm not for quick and dirty solutions... they always bite you back - I added to `ToList()` just to make it easier for jody when debugging. I don't know about the problem that qxp means but I didn't have any problem with it.. Would love to understand more from you about it. And no worries for the downvote :) I do like your answers to question and learn a lot from them so in the case you were the downvoter then it would have been something to learn from. I just don't like downvotes without understanding why

Comment: Gilad - Actually I've just checked it and can guarantee you that there is no problem (if OP is using the latest EF6) using `Except` if both parts are `IQueryable`s, like in your code (`db.Schedule` and `db.WorkingHours`). Anyway, I'm sure you "helped him", so cheers and tick :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - Thanks :) much appreciated :) just in general - so I can better test it myself in the future - how do you set up a quick way to test it - without too many things? I usually use `List<dynamic>` but this isn't really bullet proof for when I have a case of linq to entities...

Comment: I'm using the old school way - just have a ready test project with EF where I can put quickly whatever I want :)

Comment: @IvanStoev - might try that myslef :P. Thanks again for the check